# Javascript toLocaleDateString() returning extra values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

i'm getting date from my javascript function as below

```
var d = new Date(checkboxes[i].defaultValue).toLocaleDateString();
```

when i'm trying to see it in code behind Quick Watch window it's showing the value as eg. `6/27/2006` but when i pass it to a SQL Query as a parameter its getting passed in a format:

`‎|6|‎/‎|22|‎/|‎2006`

what will be the reason

**EDIT**

the symbols getting inserted into date while passing to sql query are not exactly PIPES as show above. it's like as shown in pic below

[image]

Comment: ‎|6|‎/‎|22|‎/|‎2006 Is this format sent from the javascript or from c#?

Comment: getting date value from javascript into c# code and passing it as a value in sql parameter.in quickwatch before sending to sql query i'm able to see correct value.but when i copy and paste the same value in sql server management studio getting value as shown in above pic